# Bing Maps 7 Polygon Events not firing when pushed to EntityCollection

Tags: bing-maps

When I push my Polygon to an EntityCollection, the mouseover, mouseout, and click events do not fire.  If I push the Polygon directly to the map, they do.

Events on Pushpins that are added to the EntityCollection fire correctly.

I have tried putting a zIndex on the EntityCollection (based on reading another post), but this made no difference.

In the Click event, the e.targetType is 'map' when I click on the polygon.

I am using IE11 to test this.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. Try setting the drawShapesInSingleLayer option on the map: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342813.aspx

```
map.getMode().setOptions({ drawShapesInSingleLayer: true });
```

Comment: I just tried this solution and didn't have any luck.

Comment: Add the click event to the polygon, not the map.

Comment: This does not work. Additionally, if this is a "known issue" why is it still not fixed 2.5 years later?

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/fix-ie11-mouse-events-in-bing-maps-v7/ The V7 control was released about 5 or 6 years ago and has only had critical fixes in recent years.

Comment: I intend to undo my down vote from yesterday. After several hours of troubleshooting yesterday, I figured out my issue. I am using the WKTModule for the map, and adding the mouseover event to the shape that is returned from a call to the WKTModule's Read method. However, sometimes that Read method returns an EventCollection, not a shape (e.g. in the case of a Multipolygon WKT). Since EventCollections don't have events, the events don't work. I still don't understand why this breaks ALL events on ALL polygons, but I was able to fix it by looping through the EventCollections and attaching there.

Comment: @rbrundritt Your blog post from the comments did it after **hours** of searching... You should edit it in in your answer